curve_fit popt is only returning one parameter when my function has two
I am trying to understand why my curve_fit is only producing one optimized parameter when I have created the function using two, td and tr. The number is it producing also does not make sense as I am testing things with a dataset with known parameters.
Here is my current code. I had to add return conv to the function otherwise I got an operand error saying there were two types, float and NoneType.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

data = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
time = data["time"]
TA = data["amp"]
y0 = 0
t0 = 0.13 #put in t0 here
IRS = 0.1 #put IRS here
mx = 1 #put max/min amp of raw here
l = 1
pi = 3.14
a = 1 #amplitude for gaussian

def func(td, tr):
    t = np.array(time) #building signal test code
    signal = np.array([(l*(np.exp(-(t-t0)/td)-np.exp(-(t-t0)/tr)))]) #creates signal
    np.nan_to_num(signal, copy=False, nan=0.00, posinf=0, neginf=0)
    signal[signal < 0] = 0 #replaces all negative numbers with 0
    signal = signal.flatten() #makes 1D array
    #uncomment following line if bleach and not IA
    #signal = signal*-1
    n = np.size(time) #convolution while moving Gaussian center to each time value
    matrix = []
    for i in time:
        tc = i
        for j in time:
            gauss = np.array(a*np.exp(-((j-tc)/IRS)**2))
            product = np.convolve(signal, gauss, mode='full')
            matrix.append(product)
    matrix = np.array(matrix)
    conv = np.sum(matrix, axis=0)
    conv = np.delete(conv, np.s_[n:])
    
    max = np.nanmax(conv)
    conv = (conv/max)*mx
    return conv

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, time, TA)
print(popt)


See the documentation of curve_fit():

Assumes ydata = f(xdata, *params) + eps.

In other words, one of the parameters passed to f() is the xdata that curve_fit() is fitting. Once it has passed xdata as the td parameter, there is only one parameter left.
To fix this, you should add time as the first parameter to func().

The answer by Nick ODell is correct, however I would like to elaborate.
A function to be fitted must always take the x position at which the function is to be calculated as a first argument. This is then followed by parameters to be optimized. This is not unique to scipy's curve fit, this is how all model optimization works. (See for comparison Maximum Likelyhood Estimation). Define your function like this:
def model(x_position, *parameters):
  #put some code here that defines your function

Maybe it would benefit your intuition to actually plot your data. Your x-position would be your x-axis and your returned value would be your y-position, so your function would look something like this:
def func(t, td, tr):
    #some code here
    return conv #prediction for what the y-data at position x should be
   

